# Extract a value from a JsonDocument

Tags: c++, json, arduino

noob question about float number in arduino and extracting values from a json doc.
I'm doing an HTTP request to Ipstack to get latitude and longitude values with this function:

```
void gps(){
  
    //Declare an object of class HTTPClient
    HTTPClient http;  

    //Specify request destination and fields
    http.begin("http://api.ipstack.com/check?access_key=233bf289dff160082dd3e5d915ce3135&fields=latitude,longitude");  
    //Send the request
    int httpCode = http.GET();                                  

    //Check the returning code
    if (httpCode > 0) { 
      //Get the request response payload
      payload = http.getString(); 
      //Print the response payload
      Serial.println(payload); 

      DynamicJsonDocument doc(512);
      DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, payload);

      
      float latitudine  = doc["latitude"];
      float longitudine = doc["longitude"];

      Serial.println(latitudine);
      Serial.println(longitudine);

      
    }
    //Close connection
    http.end();  
 
}//end of GPS
```

When I serial print the payload I get these values:

```
{"latitude":45.47200012207031,"longitude":9.192000389099121}
```

But when I try to serial print the two variables "latitudine" and "longitudine" I get these values:

```
45.47
9.19
```

How can I get all the decimals? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to arduino documentation of function [print](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/print/), float values are rounded to 2 digits by default. You can, however, specify how many digits you want to have in a second parameter of `print`, e.g. as

```
Serial.println(latitudine, 4);
```

Note that datatype `float` might not be able to represent all the digits contained in your json. Use `double` then.

Comment: Ok that worked and I get all the decimals but the values are not "correct". 
This is the output I get
45.47200012207032
9.19199943542481

Comment: That's because `float` is probably not able to represent value `45.47200012207031` precisely. The precision of `float` is limited (that of `double`, too)